# MSbuild command line - Publish artifacts on specfic location

Tags: msbuild

Now I can able to build successfuly, artifacts created under obj/Debug/package/packageTmp/

can you please let me know how to publish into some other directory in same machine .

Command:

> MSBuild.exe C:\RD\DigitalTechnology\Trunk\SQLDeployment\SQLDeployment.sln /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:DeployOnBuild=true

Comment: What for a kind of project do you want to deploy?

Comment: I am using .net application , I need to publish or Deploy build artifacts through command line .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a .Net application you can use:

```
/p:OutDir=c:\My\BuildDropLocation\ProjectName
```

For a web project you have to use this statement:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish 
/p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem 
/p:DeleteExistingFiles=true 
/p:publishUrl=c:\My\BuildDropLocation\ProjectName
```

Comment: Thanks , I can able to publish artifacts by using /p:OutDir=c:\My\BuildDropLocation\ProjectName